# How to create expression for test coverage parsing in gitlab from fastlane xcov plugin?

Tags: xcode, gitlab, fastlane

Simply I need to allow gitlab to parse my output coverage files and display them for every pipeline. Is it possible?

[image]

Tihs is how I call coverage in my fastlane file:

```
lane :test do
  scan(scheme: SCHEME_NAME, code_coverage: true, clean: true, output_directory: OUTPUT_PATH + 'tests', devices: ["iPhone 8 Plus"])
  coverage
end
lane :coverage do 
  xcov(
    scheme: SCHEME_NAME,
    workspace: WORKSPACE_FILE_PATH,
    json_report: true,
    markdown_report: true,
    output_directory: OUTPUT_PATH + "coverage",
    skip_slack: true,
    only_project_targets: true
  )
end
```

This is the output:

[image]

**Can I somehow indicate the path to the index.html file with coverage?**

Comment: Maybe a crazy idea: Couldn't you just add something to your lane that reads the file and outputs it to the console? From the little I see of the regex adding interface, this seems to be for the output of the trace, not for files, and that could give you the right result.

Answer (score 1):

I think what @janpio is saying is correct, GitLab seems to only check the trace. I use fastlane with xcov, and my output looks like this:

```
+-----------+----------+
| xcov Coverage Report |
+-----------+----------+
| GreatApp  | 83.50%   |
+-----------+----------+
```

I managed to parse it with this:

```
^\|\s+GreatApp\s+\|\s+(\d+.\d+\%)\s+\|$
```